# How to change default download location to an SD card?

Tags: 14.04, unity, lts, sd-card, crouton

I put Ubuntu on a chromebook through crouton but the chromebook's memory is very small, so I have a SD card in the chromebook to expand the memory. Is there a way to make the default location for downloads a folder on the SD card? If so, please be specific since I am somewhat new to Ubuntu.