# How to set Google Chrome to ask for a download location

Tags: downloads

is there a way to get ubuntu / nautilus ask for where to store a file when downloading instead of automatically placing it in the download folder.

a similar question was asked here but without an answer. [How to change default download location to an SD card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741417/how-to-change-default-download-location-to-an-sd-card)

this is more a general question than a specific situation, but as example:

while browsing (google chrome) i decided to download asustor adm 3.0 beta and would like to place this directly on the nas. Instead of downloading it to the download folder and then relocate it.

Comment: How and what do you download?

Comment: any simple download.. so nothing to do with any download manager or torrents.

Comment: What do you call "any simple download"? Is it download in a browser? Which browser? How is nautilus related?

Comment: Your edit didn't make things clearer. Are you downloading in Firefox?

Comment: yes done in browser (chrome), how nautilus is related.. maybe it isn't at all. just assumed it was (my bad) .. i added an example in the question. i will modify it again with the browser info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Chrome you can set to always ask for a download location.

Go to Chrome settings and check this option.

Comment: Super!! exactly what i needed.. I never would've guessed it was browser related though.  My bad, in hind sight i should've figured this myself. 
Still, many thanks!

Comment: It is browser related because you download in a browser.

Comment: Nautilus can download too? oke,, i understand that thaking that in consideration my question was indeed badly stated.. i will revice it again. 
when and why would one download via nautilus though?

Comment: You can download using different software. You can do it in CLI, or other apps.

Comment: yeah i figured the cli part.. and ofcourse other apps. As said, i should've figured it had nothing to do with nautilus / ubuntu..  decided to leave the question as it is now. otherwise the asnwers will become confusing to other people reading this.